# why DozerConverter is not working?

Tags: java, type-conversion, transform, dozer

I am using dozer version 5.5.1. And i want to configure my custom converter so i have this

```
import org.dozer.DozerConverter;

import com.example.movies.api.models.response.ClientResponseDTO;

public class MyCustomConverter
    extends DozerConverter<ClientResponseDTO, String> {

    public MyCustomConverter() {
        super(ClientResponseDTO.class, String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(ClientResponseDTO source, String destination) {
        return "ClientResponseDTO Converted to string!";
    }

    @Override
    public ClientResponseDTO convertFrom(String source, ClientResponseDTO destination) {
        return new ClientResponseDTO();
    }   

}
```

Which i am loading with Spring like this:

```
@Bean
public Mapper dozerBeanMapper() {
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    List<CustomConverter> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new MyCustomConverter(ClientResponseDTO.class, String.class));
    mapper.setCustomConverters(converters);
    return mapper;
}
```

Then, i have this usage:

```
    @Autowired Mapper mapper;
    ...

    ClientResponseDTO clientResponseDTO = clientService.getClient(id);
    String conversion = this.mapper.map(clientResponseDTO, String.class);
```

And the custom converter is never being called. Do you know why is that ? Regards!

Comment: Where does this.mapper comes from ? Do you @Inject it ?

Comment: Note that your constructor doesn't need to have parameters: `public PagingDDTransformer() { super(ClientResponseDTO.class, String.class); }`

Comment: You are right! i've already changed it. I've updated the post. It still not working

Comment: The mapper is coming from injection as you said. I am using Spring 4, i am autowiring the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [dozer documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) you should add mapping to bean description.
Eg.

```
<bean id="org.dozer.Mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
<property name="mappingFiles">
<list>
  <value>systempropertymapping1.xml</value>
  <value>dozerBeanMapping.xml</value>
  <value>injectedCustomConverter.xml</value>
</list>
</property><property name="customConvertersWithId">
<map>
  <entry key="CustomConverterWithId" ref="configurableConverterBeanInstance1" />
  <entry key="CustomConverterWithId2" ref="configurableConverterBeanInstance2" />
</map>
</property>
</bean>
```